# Improve minimum distance filter for pointset

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, computational-geometry

I create a minimum distance filter for points.
The function takes a stream of points (x1,y1,x2,y2...) and removes the corresponding ones.

```
void minDistanceFilter(vector<float> &points, float distance = 0.0)
{
    float p0x, p0y;
    float dx, dy, dsq;
    float mdsq = distance*distance; // minimum distance square

    unsigned i, j, n = points.size();

    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        p0x = points[i];
        p0y = points[i+1];

        for(j=0; j<n; j+=2)
        {
            //if (i == j) continue; // discard itself (seems like it slows down the algorithm)

            dx = p0x - points[j];   // delta x (p0x - p1x)
            dy = p0y - points[j+1]; // delta y (p0y - p1y)

            dsq = dx*dx + dy*dy; // distance square

            if (dsq < mdsq)
            {
                auto del = points.begin() + j;
                points.erase(del,del+3);
                n = points.size(); // update n
                j -= 2; // decrement j
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem that is very slow, due to it tests all points against all points (n^2).

**How could it be improved?**

Comment: You probably want a [quadtree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quadtree) about now.

Comment: Bulding a quadtree is also relatively slow. It would be efficient if I made the distance test more than once. Isn't it?

Comment: @Armin: That's okay, but I need to perform the test only once on a dataset. So always building a quadtree on a new dataset to perform a single test is pretty inefficient in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kd-trees or range trees could be used for your problem.  However, if you want to code from scratch and want something simpler, then you can use a hash table structure.  For each point (a,b), hash using the key (round(a/d),round(b/d)) and store all the points that have the same key in a list.  Then, for each key (m,n) in your hash table, compare all points in the list to the list of points that have key (m',n') for all 9 choices of (m',n') where m' = m + (-1 or 0 or 1) and n' = n + (-1 or 0 or 1).  These are the only points that can be within distance d of your points that have key (m,n).  The downside compared to a kd-tree or range tree is that for a given point, you are effectively searching within a square of side length 3*d for points that might have distance d or less, instead of searching within a square of side length 2*d which is what you would get if you used a kd-tree or range tree.  But if you are coding from scratch, this is easier to code; also kd-trees and range trees are kinda overkill if you only have one universal distance d that you care about for all points.

Answer (score 2):

Look up range tree, e.g. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree .  You can use this structure to store 2-dimensional points and very quickly find all the points that lie inside a query rectangle.  Since you want to find points within a certain distance d of a point (a,b), your query rectangle will need to be [a-d,a+d]x[b-d,b+d] and then you test any points found inside the rectangle to make sure they are actually within distance d of (a,b).  Range tree can be built in O(n log n) time and space, and range queries take O(log n + k) time where k is the number of points found in the rectangle.  Seems optimal for your problem.